# Link NIB/Xib - Objective C - xCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a cocoa application. With two NIB/XIB files, one of them is the main (first) window that opens. The second NIB/XIB has some extra windows there.

How do I, for example, in objective c link one NIB button to another?

I know this is a very simple question, but I just can't find the answer.

Comment: I have a window in one NIB/Xib, how do i make a button that opens a window in another NIB/Xib (InterfaceBuilder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You link (via IBAction) the action of a button from the first window (xib) to some Objective-C method.

This method contains code that does whatever you need with objects from the second xib.
(e.g. it might use NSBundle to load the second xib and bring forward one of the windows, etc).